# How do I set a certain number of options in select 2?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I need to make an analog of the size attribute in the Select2 plugin as in the default select. I can't find it in the docks.
Here's how implemented in default

Sorry for English :)

[image]

Comment: Can you please explain a little bit more?

Answer (score 0):

In html you can use `disabled` ether on the entire selection or option as showing in your image, here is an example :

```html
  <select>
    <option value="1" disabled>option 1</option>
    <option value="2">option 2</option>
    <option value="3">option 3</option>
    <option value="4" disabled>option 4</option>
  </select>
```

as you can see you can't select option 1 and 4